# sqlite3 install issues on mac os sierra

Tags: sqlite3-ruby

Hi I am very new at what im doing here. I have tried following a couple different install guides for installing ruby on rails and seem to get stuck at the same point each time and it has to do with sqlite3 it gives me an error message that looks like this. I don't know how to uninstall it so I can try to start over and do it again. Error message is below

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.5'` succeeds before bundling

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same error. In opening the mkmf.log file There were lines like these:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
>   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_sqlite3_libversion_number", referenced from:
>         _t in conftest-265d8e.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>
> ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.a, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.a
>   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_sqlite3_libversion_number", referenced from:
>         _t in conftest-265d8e.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

I just removed the two files to solve the problem.

`rm /usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.a`

`rm /usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.dylib`